# c# web scraping to get URL from html

Tags: c#

I am trying to scrape a website and get a URL from it, I am using htmlagilitypack and the code below:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("http://putlocker.ist/scorpion-season-1-episode-1/");

foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@id='vplayer_media']/video"))
{
    string whatever = link.OuterHtml;
    textBox1.Text = whatever;
}
```

I used opera's developer tools to copy the XPath which came out as this:

```
//*[@id="vplayer_media"]/video
```

I couldn't use it because of double quotes so I replaced it with

```
@"//*[@id=""vplayer_media""]/video"
```

but I get the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you copy/paste stuff, make sure you copy everything. You missed the *

Comment: I guess, single quote and double quote work the same for XPath, but I hope you understand that you can insert a double quote in a string by escaping it like this `\"`.

Comment: oops, thanks @rene, fixed it, but now I get object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: I give it a parameter though, I must be doing it incorrectly

Comment: There is no video tag on the page without login.

Comment: thats odd @AlexanderPetrov I am not logged in, I tried that class above it: @"//*[@id=""vplayer_media""]" and still got the same error

Comment: There is no `id='vplayer_media'` attribute  on the page without login. You must be logged in to get access to the real data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the double-quotes in your xpath:

```
"//[@id=\"vplayer_media\"]/video"
```

Or use double-double-quotes with a 'literal'

```
@"//[@id=""vplayer_media""]/video"
```

Comment: I get object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: the problem is that the xpath is not valid. There is a * missing and with that the question is a simply typo problem.

Comment: (@"//*[@id=""vplayer_media""]/video") I added it in, how is it still incorrect?

Comment: Single quote `'` completely legal in xpath.